# System settings force close when opening widget picker

Tags: android, android-widget, appwidgetprovider

My users report a crash that occurs when they try to pick a widget with my application (not a launcher app).
I'm using the standard widget picker code and it always worked and still works on all devices, **except on LG G2 and LG G3**.

I've found some similar questions but they all refer to the crash that Android 2.1 suffered from that was solved with the empty data workaround (which is already implemented in my code).

Also used an [alternative way](https://github.com/alexesprit/appwidgetpicker) to get the widgets, without the official picker - which works, but requires the app to be a system app for the BIND_APPWIDGET permission.

Anyone experienced this issue as well and maybe found a workaround or a solution?

Thanks

**Here's the code:**

```
public static void selectWidget(AppWidgetHost appWidgetHost, final Activity activity) {
        try {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
            Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);
            pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            addEmptyData(pickIntent);
            activity.startActivityForResult(pickIntent, R.id.REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.widget_config_no_activity), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * This avoids a bug in the com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity, which is used
     * to select widgets. This just adds empty extras to the intent, avoiding the bug. See
     * more: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4272
     */
    private static void addEmptyData(Intent pickIntent) {
        ArrayList customInfo = new ArrayList();
        pickIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_CUSTOM_INFO, customInfo);
        ArrayList customExtras = new ArrayList();
        pickIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_CUSTOM_EXTRAS, customExtras);
    }
```

**Here's the crash stacktrace:**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xhdpi-1280x960/ic_launcher_calendar.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02007e
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xhdpi-1280x960/ic_launcher_calendar.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02007e
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2156)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:789)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity.createItem(AppWidgetPickActivity.java:139)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity.createItem(AppWidgetPickActivity.java:47)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetLoader.putAppWidgetItems(AppWidgetLoader.java:145)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetLoader.putInstalledAppWidgets(AppWidgetLoader.java:209)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetLoader.getItems(AppWidgetLoader.java:182)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity.getItems(AppWidgetPickActivity.java:92)
            at com.android.settings.ActivityPicker.onCreate(ActivityPicker.java:143)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity.onCreate(AppWidgetPickActivity.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-xhdpi-1280x960/ic_launcher_calendar.png
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:415)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2147)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:789)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity.createItem(AppWidgetPickActivity.java:139)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity.createItem(AppWidgetPickActivity.java:47)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetLoader.putAppWidgetItems(AppWidgetLoader.java:145)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetLoader.putInstalledAppWidgets(AppWidgetLoader.java:209)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetLoader.getItems(AppWidgetLoader.java:182)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity.getItems(AppWidgetPickActivity.java:92)
            at com.android.settings.ActivityPicker.onCreate(ActivityPicker.java:143)
            at com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity.onCreate(AppWidgetPickActivity.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Both the LG G2 and LG G3 have very high pixel densities. Is it possible that there's a corrupted version of ic_launcher_calendar.png?

Comment: @DaveS perhaps but this is a drawable that the system holds (com.android.settings)... I know the developer of WearableWidgets managed to find a workaround using the library I linked above but I have no idea how he managed to dismiss the use of the BIND_APPWIDGET permission.

Comment: You can get AppWidgetProviderInfo from the AppWidgetManager using the id you get, which has an icon property, perhaps you can verify that and at least handle the problem rather than crashing.

Comment: @DaveS Tried that... it returns null as well. Probably also because of the missing permission and the fact I can't bind the widget to the generated id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I managed to solve the issue on Android 4.1 and above (API 16), using the `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND` Intent. For some reason, Google states that we must add the `BIND_APPWIDGET` permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml` in order for this to work, but it works for me anyway (tested on multiple devices). I use the `bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed` method to check if I need to request the bind or not.

I still haven't figure out how to bind widgets prior to Android 4.1, even with reflection to `bindAppWidgetId`. This is good enough for me know but I'll accept any other answer with a solution for pre-JellyBean (Android below 4.1)

Comment: Only 1% of devices are using Android older than 4.1 these days (https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), so the version of Android should no longer be an issue.